# Open CV Issue with Imgcodecs.imread In Loop Java

Tags: java, loops, opencv, debugging

I'm running the below code in a loop and injecting the filePath. I know 100%  the file path is correct. For some reason the below code fails when I let the loop run. HOWEVER, if i set a break point anywhere each time I "continue" it works without any issues.

Why the heck do I need to have a breakpoint hit to have this code work?

```
private static String FindCircles(String filePath) {
    
    Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread(filePath, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);

    if( src.empty() ) {
        System.out.println("Error opening image!");
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: What does "fails" mean? Be specific.

Comment: src is empty and the image doesn’t load

Comment: Is this being called from multiple threads simultaneously? If it works when setting a breakpoint, that's often related to thread issues.